# Chatbot con Laravel y Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Buenas noches a todos!

Espero poder encontrar ayuda aqui, estoy tratando de realizar un chatbot usando como base este chatbot en php pero lo necesito en laravel

Mi problema radica en que cuando hago click en Enviar, en la Consola me marca 500
Internal Server Error post, por lo cual imagino que mi error esta en el java script pero no logro descifrar donde, ya agregue lo del CSRF-TOKEN y aun así no logro que funcione.

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano, aquí dejo el enlace del Chatbot en el que me base.

[ENLACE DONDE ME BASE](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/chatbot-using-php-with-mysql/)

Este es mi codigo:

**bot.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Geriatree App</title>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bot.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Geriatree Chat</div>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="bot-inbox inbox">
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="msg-header">
                <p>¡Hola!, ¿Como puedo ayudarte?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="typing-field">
        <div class="input-data">
            <input id="data" type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje.." required>
            <button id="send-btn">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send-btn").on("click", function(){
            $value = $("#data").val();
            $msg = '<div class="user-inbox inbox"><div class="msg-header"><p>'+ $value +'</p></div></div>';
            $(".form").append($msg);
            $("#data").val('');

            // start ajax code
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('Pacientes.messagebot')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'text='+$value,
                success: function(result){
                    $replay = '<div class="bot-inbox inbox"><div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div><div class="msg-header"><p>'+ result +'</p></div></div>';
                    $(".form").append($replay);
                    // when chat goes down the scroll bar automatically comes to the bottom
                    $(".form").scrollTop($(".form")[0].scrollHeight);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::post('/message',[
    'uses'=>'PacientesControlador@messagebot',
    'as'=>'Pacientes.messagebot'
]);
```

**PacientesControlador.php**

```
    public function messagebot(Request $request)
    {
        $getMesg = $request->input('text');

        //checking user query to database query
        $check_data = chatbot::where('queries','LIKE','%'.$getMesg.'%');

// if user query matched to database query we'll show the reply otherwise it go to else statement
        if(count($check_data) > 0){
            //storing replay to a varaible which we'll send to ajax
            $replay = $check_data->replies;
            echo $replay;
        }else{
            echo "Lo siento no entiendo lo que dices";
        }
```

Comment: El error 500 es un error en el código de tu servidor, para saber que es lo que realmente pasa abre el log de errores en Laravel y pega aqui el mensaje de error que ahi se grabó

Comment: @BetaM En Laravel no siempre, por cierto ya lo corregí, el problema estaba en el controlador

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con no siempre?, un error 500 es un fallo en tu código de servidor como tu mismo me lo acabas de confirmar al decir que era algo en tu controlador

Comment: Además considera responder a tu pregunta para que asi no quede abierta